# How to securely implement Facebook login and design database?

Tags: android, database, api, authentication, facebook-login

I'm making Android app and an API, I need to implement Facebook login. I'm thinking about this:

1. Login button in Android app, get FB user id after login.
2. Send FB user id to my API `login` method.
3. In API, check if sent FB user id is in database. If it isn't, we insert a new record in our database, like `id: 506, facebook-id:45645679843`.
4. If it is in database or after inserting new record, we return some kind of access token.
5. We use that access token for future API calls.

However, my solution looks very insecure. If someone makes an API `login` call with not his FB user id, he will get access token for that account. So how do I fix this? How can I check, if login was valid?

**EDIT:**
can I get something like login token after login, send that token to my API and check if it's valid there? Or FB SDK doesn't have such functionality?

**EDIT2:**
what do you think about this approach?

1. Login button in Android app, get FB access token after login.
2. Send FB access token to my API `login` method.
3. In our API, we make a call to FB's Graph API using access token to get FB user id.
4. We check if this FB user id is in database. If it isn't, we insert a new record in our database.
5. If it was in database or after inserting new record, we return our own generated access token.
6. We use that accesss token for future API calls.

Comment: i have exactly the same issue in my app. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible to make this kind of validation for the system structure that you have planned. However, you could solve the problem like this.
For the API that you are building, make sure that a 'secret-token' is sent along with the FBuser id. This secret token

> ex. yourapp-0122120123--123i1eqwejoe19_qqw13e!!sdokdf

will be only known to you, so even if someone else sends a request, if the secret-token is not present in the parameters passed, you can recognize that this is a invalid API call.

My assumption here is that the FBuserID is automatically inserted in the request and you are not allowing the user to manually enter the parameters there, basically all things are happening through code, else the user could make a fake request:-)

Comment: But if someone decompiles an apk, he will find out about it! Also, I can change my structure, I didn't even start, I'm in planning stage right now.

Comment: I don't know much about decompiling an APK. Check once if the secret-key can be obtained. If the structure is not yet decided, you could make the user login to facebook using OAUTH2 like system, so that he is automatically redirected to redirect URI you have mentioned

Comment: how do I do it? I need more info, links or something.

Comment: http://oauth.net/2/  and this https://github.com/wareninja/generic-oauth2-login-for-android

Comment: can you check **EDIT2**? What do you think about this approach?

Comment: Yes that is a good workaround, i see no flaw at first sight;-) If i think of one, il surely get back

Comment: U cant realay on access token cause if the user changes it password the access token will also change, I m having the same issuer i guess I ll have to add two plateforms for the sdk, one for android and the second for php sdk.

Comment: Let the access token change. He is not storing the access token. When his  API receives the access-token, he will get user id from the graphapi using that token. So, it will not be an issue even if user changes password, as userid for the user for an app is constant